# zypper refresh not working: "Refreshing service 'cloud_update'."

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, opensuse, suse, zypper

I'm on Google Cloud and I'm trying to update from the SUSE repositories, but I am unable. For example when I run this:

```
 # zypper refresh
```

I get:

```
Refreshing service 'cloud_update'.
```

For a long time, then I get:

```
Timeout exceeded when accessing `'http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/database:/postgresql/SLE_12_SP3/repodata/repomd.xml'.`
```

The VPN Gateway logs indicate:

```
D  sending DPD request 
D  generating INFORMATIONAL request 878 [ ] 
D  sending packet: from [Google IP address here][500] to [my IP address here][500] (80 bytes) 
D  received packet: from [my IP address here][500] to [Google IP address here][500] (80 bytes) 
D  parsed INFORMATIONAL response 878 [ ]
```

**What is going on? Is the SUSE repo down?**

If I put the link above in my browser I get:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<repomd xmlns="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/repo" xmlns:rpm="http://linux.duke.edu/metadata/rpm">
<revision>1516763417</revision>
<tags>
<repo>
obsrepository://build.opensuse.org/server:database:postgresql/SLE_12_SP3
</repo>
</tags>
<data type="primary">
<checksum type="sha256">
b728c544d7f29705060e8c13e9f3e65fc4b4ae688abfaf950fce2a69ae6bce4a
</checksum>
<open-checksum type="sha256">
0806dae0c956c56000c214d7027f47c180fefe0d3b751bb7b0bfff23df8e2aef
</open-checksum>
<location href="repodata/b728c544d7f29705060e8c13e9f3e65fc4b4ae688abfaf950fce2a69ae6bce4a-primary.xml.gz"/>
<timestamp>1516763417</timestamp>
<size>240325</size>
<open-size>2523553</open-size>
</data>
<data type="filelists">
<checksum type="sha256">
2a21f81192105b74d873f49136e1490fc390dfaf7f1f6b76bfe27b8dbb970e15
</checksum>
<open-checksum type="sha256">
3e86d4e3323cd401d766dd4837a5f3ab701ed5c3840b4d5fc340b5ec8a7ff678
</open-checksum>
<location href="repodata/2a21f81192105b74d873f49136e1490fc390dfaf7f1f6b76bfe27b8dbb970e15-filelists.xml.gz"/>
<timestamp>1516763417</timestamp>
<size>510797</size>
<open-size>6503598</open-size>
</data>
<data type="other">
<checksum type="sha256">
ebf8fa6a503f73d046ce3ceac4d5549ba82d635f2284aabba740156a40c223ec
</checksum>
<open-checksum type="sha256">
ae1032a71dfd8089e96ecb9f149bb947d244e0482696700b8edcf1d4c19c2293
</open-checksum>
<location href="repodata/ebf8fa6a503f73d046ce3ceac4d5549ba82d635f2284aabba740156a40c223ec-other.xml.gz"/>
<timestamp>1516763417</timestamp>
<size>3494469</size>
<open-size>15687434</open-size>
</data>
</repomd>
```

I didn't come up with much doing online searches.

```
# cat /etc/os-release
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12-SP3"
VERSION_ID="12.3"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 SP3"
ID="sles"
ANSI_COLOR="0;32"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:suse:sles:12:sp3"
```

Comment: As of now, SUSE repo is not down. Just now, I zypper refresh successfully to refresh all repositories. Seems your VM is not able to reach required URL over the internet. There might be some firewall blocking this update.  Have you tried PING or traceroute to www.Opensuse.org from your instances to review the bottleneck?

Comment: I will do that tomorrow. Thanks!